# SQLite .tables command - disable column output format

Tags: sqlite

When I execute `sqlite database.db .tables` command, it returns list of tables in the following format:

```
table1   table2     table3                
table4   table4     table6
```

I would like to switch it to:

```
table1
table2
table3
```

How can I change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQLite shell tool does not allow customizing the `.tables` output format.

Try piping the output through `fmt -w1`.